# Angular2- Observable issues

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using `toPromise()` and its working fine from the website but I get the following errors when I am in code view.

[image: Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable']

[[image: Invalid module name in augmentation... 1]]

I suspect its something todo with my local modules.

The code for the components is

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
import './rxjs-extensions';

import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';



@Injectable()

export class TokenValidatorService {


    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    validateToken(token: string): Promise<string>  {
        return this.http.get('/api/downloader/' + token + '/valid')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                return response.text()
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getDownloadUrl(token: string, pin: string): Promise<string> {
        return this.http.get('/api/downloader/' + token + '/' + pin + '/getlink')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                return response.text()
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  }
}
```

and my systemjs.config.js is

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.min.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.min.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

You will notice that I load directly from `unpkg` I suspect that this is why it works in runtime. This is a VS Project it VS is taking care of the typescript etc, the tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Edit

It's discussed in the following pages

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1696 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518

I have upgraded to TS2 and I still have the issue.

Comment: Try adding a reference specifically to the RxJS toPromise like: `import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";`

Comment: I have tried this and I still get this issue.